# React: Set the state of a parent based on child's state?

Tags: reactjs, parent-child

First time working with React.
In summary I need to have a child update the state of a parent component, although I've successfully passed a callback function to the child it doesn't behave the way I expect.
I have a component App which renders a child component LoginOverlay.

The component App is written as follows:

```
export default class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      userID:'',
      loginState:'waiting',
      loginError:'',
    };
  }

  handleLogin(un, pw){
    //just try setting a state as if the API call came back with an error code
    this.setState({
      loginError:'Wrong Password',
    })
  }

  render() {
      return (
      <div className="App">
        {/*login overlay*/}
        <LoginOverlay loginError={this.state.loginError} loginState={this.state.loginState} parentCallback={this.handleLogin}/>
        UserID:{this.state.userID}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The child component is written as follows:

```
export default class LoginOverlay extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.userNameChange=this.userNameChange.bind(this);
    this.passwordChange=this.passwordChange.bind(this);
    this.submitHandler=this.submitHandler.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      username:'',
      password:'',
      loginState:this.props.loginState,
      loginError:this.props.loginError,
    };
  }

  userNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      username: event.target.value
    });
  }

  passwordChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      password: event.target.value
    })
  }

  submitHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.username!=='' && this.state.password !=='') {
      this.setState({
        loginState:'loading',
        loginError:'',
      })
      this.props.parentCallback(this.state.username, this.state.password);
    }
    else {
      this.setState({
        loginError:'Fill out the form, please!'
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
      let bottompane = null;
      switch(this.state.loginState) {
        case 'waiting':
          bottompane =  <div className="login-ButtonContainer">
                          <input
                            type="submit"
                            value="Log In"
                            className="login-button"
                          />
                        </div>
          break;
        case 'loading':
          bottompane =  <div className="login-ButtonContainer">
                          {/*copypasted from loading.io*/}
                          <div className="lds-spinner"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
                        </div>
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }

      let errorText = null;
      switch(this.state.loginError) {
        case '':
        break;
        default:
          errorText=<div className="login-errortext">{this.state.loginError}</div>
        break;
      }

      return(
      <div className="loginOverlay">
        <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler} className="login-box">
          <label>
            Username:
          </label>
          <input
            className="login-field"
            type="text"
            onChange={this.userNameChange}
          />
          <br/>
          <label>
            Password:
          </label>
          <input
            className="login-field"
            type="password"
            onChange={this.passwordChange}
          />
          <br/>
            {bottompane}
            {errorText}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

However, after I hit the submit button and handeLogin is executed, the loginError state does not update (I check using console.log(this.state.loginError)). I wonder if it's my approach that is wrong? Or my syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to mirror/copy props into state like this:

```
// This is bad news:
this.state = {
  loginState: this.props.loginState,
  loginError: this.props.loginError,
};
```

Instead, just reference `this.props.loginState` anywhere you need to know what that value is. This is what's called a “managed component” — the parent component manages the state through props.

Comment: That's good to know, and I'll make those changes. However, I'm still not able to use this.setState from the callback?

Comment: @BoThompson You can use `setState` in a callback, but since you're referencing `this.state.loginError` when `this` is an instance of `LoginOverlay` you never get the changes passed down as props. The props you've copied into state still reflect the props from the time the component was initialized (prop changes don't unmount and remount class-based components).

Comment: Ah, so my approach is flawed. I made both components stateful originally because I was planning to have the App component handle all API calls, and for the child to just get data. I made the child stateful so that it could quickly display a loading icon once it sends its data to the parent. Do I need to just keep that state information exclusively in the parent? Won't that bloat the parent badly after a lot of these forms are added?

Comment: @BoThompson I don't think you have to worry about the speed of prop propagation. As for architectural challenges, it's hard to say without knowing more about what you’re doing, but you may prefer an approach that has forms validating and submitting using hooks locally and only communicating a generic status up to the app level (i.e. if you need to block the whole app while a form is submitting).

Comment: That gives me food for thought. Thank you.

Comment: To make this answer more clear to future onlookers, I suggest you edit in the part about how "prop changes don't unmount and remount class-based components".